# Geolocation and getting a city from an input address (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, geolocation

The app I'm building needs to be able to match up users to events based on the city/town they're in. I'm still relatively new to Rails and completely new to Geolocation and using locations in an app. I'd figured on a design where users have one or many cities, and events would have one city which I'd hoped to extract without specifically asking the user for it, by getting it from the event address entered.

Mostly to provide some outside checking to help get the address entered correctly and consistently, but also to show a map, I installed this jquery address picker (https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker). Unfortunately the data returned by Google doesn't include a city but a "locality" or an "administrative area" that doesn't correlate reliably to city names. The localities being returned are more like what we in my home town would call "suburbs". What I need to procure is a city so I can allow users to search all events in their city rather than just the ones in their suburb.

Can anyone offer advice on how I could go about doing this? Many thanks.

Edit: Should maybe add that I'm wanting to do geocoding client-side so I don't run into problems with Google Maps limits or have to pay for geocoding etc.

Comment: I recommend you to add some examples of addresses that you have issues with, and the expected city name so people can understand better and test it if they want to.

Comment: Good idea; sorry, I just assumed other people would have had the same issue and know what I'm talking about. Say I search for "58 Mollison Street, West End". West End is a suburb in Brisbane (city), Queensland (state), Australia (country :P). The locality that is returned is "South Brisbane". That might be the name of a political district or something like that but nobody who lives here and goes out to places would use the term "South Brisbane" to refer to West End in Brisbane; you'd use the suburb name "West End", and the city name "Brisbane". So I want to let people search under "Brisbane".

Answer (score 1):

There are some gems that provide you with that and may others geo related features, like calculating distances.

Here are the 2 most famous: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder and https://github.com/imajes/geokit

In the future I highly recommend you to head to https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ to see what is available as a gem already and see what is the most popular at the moment.

Comment: Hey Ismael, thanks, I've seen those two already and bookmarked them already for use when it comes to calculating distances like you say. From what I can see though using those to generate a city name isn't possible because they're relying on the same data being used by the address picker I'm already using. They only provide a locality/neighbourhood/suburb or state, with no city. It seems to me like I must need a database of some kind that connects localities to cities. Is this what experienced programmers of this kind of thing do in this situation?

Comment: I have no idea what people use but have you tested if they has the same issue? You can also try a different geo service provider.

Comment: Seeing how others solve the same issue is what I'm trying to do here. :)

Comment: okok. Then you should wait for someone else with experience on this give you an answer. I hope you can solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

For raw address info, use [Google Maps API Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) which accepts lat/lon inputs and returns street address components.  Modern browsers support location awareness (geolocation), with user permission, and will give you a lat/lon that "tends to be close" to where the browser is.  That will probably get you a correct city/town in most cases.

The maps API is part of Google's broad suite of API tools -- there are gems that handle any Google API (well, most of them), or check out [Google Maps for Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails), which will at the very least give you a good head start on how to use the API.

But if you're looking to validate postal code, this method will come up short, since the location awareness will vary in accuracy depending on browser, device (more accurate for mobile), the connection, population density, network coverage, and so on.  Also, calling the

If you can get GPS-accurate lat/lon then it will be much more accurate ... except in some cases like in large cities, a single building will have its own postal code, so a few feet one way or the other might matter.

Comment: Postcodes really don't matter to me. I just want the user to type in an address and for me to be able to query somewhere for the city name. Maybe Google Maps' data is just all wrong for where I'm living. It does promise "locality indicates an incorporated city or town political entity". That's not what I'm getting. "South Brisbane" isn't a city. Since I'm wanting my app to be useable in my local area first and foremost, Google Maps alone doesn't seem like it's going to be a solution. Thanks though.

Comment: Hmm -- maybe you're right that Maps API isn't complete, but the Reverse Geocoding section of the link I provided is for "translating a location on the map into a human-readable address", and the example output they provide various types, including street address and formatted address.  If it's not working well where you are, then I'll let it rest, but I did want to ensure your're looking at the same API I am.

Comment: Thanks for double checking, maybe I am missing something you're alluding to, but I'm noting that this too returns a locality... which in my example is again going to be South Brisbane, which isn't a city. Thanks again though..